# Which one is correct as adjective “protruding” or “protruded”?

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives

I saw a phrase saying “protruding eye”. Shouldn’t it be “protruded” ? I couldn’t understand why *-ing* is used instead of *-ed* and how the *-ing* form is used as an adjective here.

Comment: Please give the whole phrase. "protruding" is almost certainly correct but we can't be 100% certain without the full context.

Comment: most adjectives are ing. That said, his eye protruded: He has a protruding eye.

Comment: @Lambie -- Your comment is the start of a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Many adjectives are ing, though there are also ones with ed or the irregular past participle. The meanings can change, too.

- **protruding** eye [like lizards, a regular type of eye for a lizard]
- **protruded** eye would be a regular eye that had damage done to it. A forensic analysis by have a term like that in it after a crime or accident.
- **broken** record [as in for music]; you sound like a broken record (repetitive); one that has been broken.
- **breaking** news: news that is emerging in the present time. Broken news is not a term.
- **flying** aces: pilots from WWI.
- flown routes: routes that  have been flown by a pilot.

When the ing form is used, it is just a regular adjective. When the past participle is used, it often means something was done to the object.

- moving vehicles, vehicles in motion, that are moving
- moved vehicles, vehicles that have been moved
- floating beacons, ones that float
- floated beacons, ones that were put in the water and floated

You can often take the verb and analyze it as: an x that [verb] versus an x that has been [verb,past participle].

Often that helps to make the meaning clear.

Answer (score 4):

**protruding** itself is an adjective and it means sticking out or projecting.
Therefore it is correct to say **protruding eyes**
[**Protruding**](https://www.google.com/search?ei=aX2WXI6_M4_bz7sPut-mqAg&q=meaning+of+protruding&oq=meaning+of+protruding&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0l2j0i67j0l6.23576.31336..31577...2.0..5.661.6549.0j4j19j0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..0i71j35i39j0i131j0i131i67j0i20i263j0i10.zCEnQWxzTTg)

Answer (score 3):

[Protrude](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protrude) is a verb.

Some verbs with the added suffix **-ing** act as adjectives.  Protruding here is defining the characteristic of eyes.

Similar adjectives are "**Interesting**" ,"**Exciting**"

**-ed** is also used to turn verbs into adjectives. For example "**Excited**" and "**Exciting**" both are adjectives with different suffix